# What ever happened to the Free People Of Earth?

Tags: enders-game

After the Free People of Earth took over almost all of Earth, except for the USA, (I don't recall this, but I read online that there was a war, and the US took over the FPOE), does the books (*Shadow* series) mention how it happened and what was the aftermath?

Please reference the books.

Comment: " I read online that there was a war, and the US took over the FPOE"? Wut? Can you provide a link? I don't recall anything remotely close in the books.

Comment: Methinks this is going to be yet another book in the Ender series.

Comment: Sorry, the grammar with the parenthetical portion is throwing me. You're saying that you read online that the US took over the FPOE? Or are you asking how the FPOE took over the Earth except for the US?

Comment: @Dima : i don't think so. Most of FPE history is pretty much explained, and the only loose end i saw was "Randall Firth".

Comment: @C.B. - You'll be wanting to read *Ended in Exile* for that one.

Answer (score 1):

The book (*that you didn't originally identify in the question*) mentions **NOTHING** of anything called "Free People of Earth". Neither the Ender's Game you nominated, nor even Ender's Shadow with its more geocentric details. Maybe it's from later within the Shadows Saga, but i wouldn't count on that.

---

[Later Edit:] After phantom42 mentioned which book actually tells the story of the *Free People*, i went over the whole of the series and re-checked them all, not just the two i believed you referred to by using the tag of "enders-game"... So here's the scoop:

- the second half of SotG mentions how FPoE started and how it evolved until "the most belligerent nations had been subdued";
- the final note on the subject was: "Only the good old USA refuses to join the FPE" (note that this is the official shortened name, not FPOE). There's no evidence of what happened next, only Peter's guess that a peaceful union would soon be possible. Note that at this point, i believe a war between US and the Hegemony wouldn't be feasible.
- the currently-latest novel, *Shadows in Flight*, while being the chronological sequel, is no longer set on Earth and (in its abridged e-book version) doesn't reveal any details about the aftermath of FPE's "taking over";
- for completeness' sake, neither of the three Lusitania volumes mention FPE at all, which makes sense considering they were published before the events of the "Shadow"s would bring forth this part of the story.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment on the question, not as answer.

Comment: The Free People of Earth figure are prominently featured in the "Shadow" series of Ender/Bean books.

Comment: @Stan : the question itself is "does the book mention how it happened". My answer is no, it doesn't mention anything about such a subject. How is that more appropriate as comment?

Comment: @phantom42 : "prominently"?!? Zero mentions in Ender's Shadow and Shadow of the Hegemon is "prominently featured in the series"? (And my conjecture concerning the Shadows Saga was a mercy comment, since the original question was tagged with Ender's Game, not the whole Enderverse.)

Comment: @C.B. The group is introduced in Shadow of the Giant. Just because it's introduced in a later book does not mean it's not prominent.

Comment: The OP does not have sufficient rep to create a new tag, so Ender's Game is the next most logical existing tag for them to use.

Comment: @phantom42 : _Shadow of the Giant_ having been the final part of the Shadow Saga for the most part of the last 10 years... Quite prominent in the **"series"** indeed. :p Also, not being able to create a tag is not a good excuse (from my POV) for the total failure to establish any kind of relevant context except "the book". But now that you've explained that i'll edit the question to include it and then dig out Giant and look the issue up.

Answer (score 1):

The Free People of Earth ain't taken over by the Americans. The book ends with Peter talking about how all the nations joined the FPE except for the US.